# R: Using typeof() on something that looks like an array but gives integer?

Tags: r

I'm using Rstudio and I don't understand why my min.pair variable looks like a list or array made from a bunch of integers but identifies as an integer. I'm trying to count how many '2' there is using `lenghts()`, but it can't seem to work.
Thanks

```
two.dozen = matrix(sum.rolls, nrow = 25,ncol = 1000)
min.pair = apply(two.dozen, 1, min)
print(min.pair)
```

[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

```
typeof(min.pair)
```

[1] "integer"

Comment: `array` is a class, not a type. Compare `class(array(1L))` and `typeof(array(1L))`. In any case, type and length are independent concepts. Compare `typeof(1L)` and `typeof(1:6)`. Have you tried `length(min.pair)`?

Comment: You might also like `sum(min.pair==2)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably confuse `lengths` with the function `length`

```
x <- rep(2, 10)

x
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

`length` will give you the amount of values in the list

```
length(x)
# [1] 10
```

`lengths` gives you the length of each item in the list, there is just one "2"

```
lengths(x)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Lets create a nested list to illustrate the difference and use better.

```
y <- rep(list(list(1, 2)), 10)

y
# List of 10
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : num 1
#   ..$ : num 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : num 1
#   ..$ : num 2
# ...
```

`length` shows us that we have 10 lists in y

```
length(y)
# [1] 10
```

`lengths` shows us that we have two values in each of the 10 lists of y

```
lengths(y)
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```